# Can we add SSL certificate to heroku app having herokuapp.com extension without having a own domain

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to SSL concept. I am having a Rails 3.2 application running on heroku.

Can anyone please clarify me about the following things:

If I am having a heroku application "http://example.herokuapp.com", can I add SSL certificate to it without having any own domain (like www.example.com). If so, could you please provide a reference url to that process.

If the above thing is possible, in future if I own a domain (like www.example.com), can I add the same SSL certificate to that domain. Or I need to have a new SSL certificate for it. Or pointing secured (https) url of that application to the new domain (like www.example.com) is sufficient?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
K. Subrahmanyam

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to buy or add anything to use SSL and HTTPS on the `.herokuapp.com` subdomain, it comes with piggyback-SSL for free out of the box. I.e.: https://example.herokuapp.com/

If you add a custom domain and want SSL on that, you also have to buy a certificate for the domain and add the relevant add-on. That's [documented on Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).

Comment: +1 Gah, why didn't I know this. I just spent the last hour trying to price shop just so I could get SSL for research purposes.